# jQuery - Pagination with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, dynamic, pagination

```
<style type="text/css">
.model {
  display: none;
}
.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<div class="model">item <span>1</span></div>
<div class="header">Add an item</div>
<div class="itemlist">
  <div>item <span>1</span></div>
  <div>item <span>2</span></div>
  <div>item <span>3</span></div>
</div>
```

If the user clicks on the header, my javascript clones *.model* and prepends *.itemlist* with it.
I would like to paginate (no need for ajax) this dynamic *.itemlist* with for example 10 items per page.
I tried 2 or 3 jquery plugins but I can't find one that manages the pagination with a dynamic list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this JQuery Plugin ?
Name is [quickPager](http://geckohub.com/tests/simplepager/demo/2/) and download from [here](http://www.geckonewmedia.com/blog/2009/7/15/simplepager---an-easy-jquery-paging-plugin).

Comment: It does not seem suitable for dynamic content.
If I add an item, how can I refresh the pagination ?